# The session driver configuration as memcached not work

Tags: php, laravel, session, memcached

I have a Laravel 8 Application in a sharehost. All forms throw me error 419 session expired, and my ISP notify me they configured the server to use memcached. I change my `.env`, `config/session.php`, `config/cache.php` and `config.app.php` , but doesn't work. Also session in others configuration is not an option, must be this. I'm new in Laravel also.

Below my files

.env file

```
APP_NAME=proyectname
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:sECc6UgBwPVVeAfI4FVRje4KZpnHhALdWbgmtTNQRaw=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://myurl

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

config/cache.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'memcached'),

    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
            'serialize' => false,
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
            'lock_connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache',
            'lock_connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'dynamodb' => [
            'driver' => 'dynamodb',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'table' => env('DYNAMODB_CACHE_TABLE', 'cache'),
            'endpoint' => env('DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],

    'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache'),

];
```

config/app.php file

```
<?php

return [

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'proyectname'),

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://myurl'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    'locale' => 'en',

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\QrCodeServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        // 'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'QrCode' => SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode::class,
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

    ],

];
```

config/session.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'memcached'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

Comment: Im confused by the statement that "the ISP configured the server to use memcached". Its up to the programmer what they use in the end. For instance, you could just use the `file` driver in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I had to configure a SESSION_STORE value. The default of `null` isn't valid. So in `config/session.php` change this value:

```
'store' => 'default_generic',
```

Alternatively, set the SESSION_STORE value to the same string in your `.env` file

Comment: in laravel 10 thats no a valid string value